# Keras binary accuracy for vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, conv-neural-network

I'm using keras to perform multilabel classification and I saw that Keras binary accuracy is defined as

```
K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)))
```

My y are vector of 25 components.
If I print just the K.equal I see a tensor of shape=(batch_size, 25) like [[True, True, True, .. ,True, True, True], .. , [True,False,True, .. , True, True, True]].

---

I would like to understand if the mean is calculated on all the values in the tensor ( and so is divided by batch_size*25) or it is calculated component by component ( and so is divided by batch_size). 
I'll explain better, I would like accuracy to count only those cases where the whole sub vector corresponds to the target vector

Answer (score 2):

Assume that

```
y_true = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]
```

and

```
y_pred = [[0.4,0.35,0.35],[0.3,0.4,0.3],[0.1,0.4,0.5],[0.1,0.5,0.4]]
```

In the given equation, first K.round, rounds your predictions:

**K.round(y_pred)** : [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

Then, K.equal checks whether these two results are equal

**K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred))** :

```
[[1==0,0==0,0==0], [0==0,1==0,0==0], [0==0,0==0,1==0],[0==0,1==0,0==0]]
```

That results

```
[[False, True, True], [True,False,True], [True,True,False], [True,False,True]]
```

What K.mean does is, simply, sums above result list as if True = 1 and False = 0 and divides all the test row counts. *(As far as i know accuracy has nothing to do with batch size.)*

```
binary_accuracy score is 8/12 = 0.66
```

On the other hand **categorical_accuracy**, which defined as follows,

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):

   return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),

                      K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),

                      K.floatx())
```

checks only the highest values of index for y_true and y_pred:

```
y_true = [0,1,2,1] 

y_pred = [0,1,2,1] 

[True,True,True,True] => categorical_accuracy = 1
```

If you use **categorical_crossentropy**, I recommend you to use categorical_accuracy for precisize results.